# Need for foo at the end of the query

Tags: pyspark, teradata

Why is there a need to have the word foo at the end of the query.

```
queryTwo = """(SELECT max(lst_updt_dt_tm) as maxDt FROM table) foo """

theTable = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(url="the url", driver = "the td driver", dbtable = queryTwo, user="xxxx", password="xxxx").load()
theTable.show();
```

If I remove the word foo, the code fails.

Comment: queryTwo = """SELECT max(lst_updt_dt_tm) as maxDt FROM DDWV21.SRVY"""

theTable = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(url="jdbc:teradata://teradata-dns-sysa.fg.rbc.com", driver = "com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver", dbtable = queryTwo, user="xxx", password="xxx").load()
theTable.show(); the error message here is 
: java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 15.10.00.33] [Error 3707] [SQLState 42000] Syntax error, expected something like a name or a Unicode delimited identifier or an 'UDFCALLNAME' keyword or '(' between the 'FROM' keyword and the 'SELECT' keyword.

Comment: Probably because subqueries have to have an alias. Try without the parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

Reverse engineering what is happening here from the error in your comment:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 15.10.00.33] [Error 3707] [SQLState 42000] Syntax error, expected something like a name or a Unicode delimited identifier or an 'UDFCALLNAME' keyword or '(' between the 'FROM' keyword and the 'SELECT' keyword.
```

It's pretty clear that your `dbtable` parameter requires a SUBQUERY as input. Whatever is happening in sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options is rewriting the query as :

```
 SELECT <something> FROM <dbtable> <possibly something more here>;
```

As such it requires that `dbtable` be a subquery which is why you must wrap it in parentheses and give it an alias `foo`.

If you read up on the documentation for [SPARK SQL](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases) You will see:

> dbtable:  The JDBC table that should be read. Note that anything that is
>   valid in a FROM clause of a SQL query can be used. For example,
>   instead of a full table you could also use a subquery in parentheses.

So you could give it a table, or, optionally, you can give it a subquery. Since it doesn't specify that the subqueries alias needs to be `foo` you could really write any legal alias name here like `mysubquery` or `"this is a poor choice for a subquery alias"` or `"f"` if you feel so inclined..